# Socket Scanner Error - SoftScan set status returned the error -43

Tags: barcode-scanner, socketscan

I am facing an error during socket barcode scanner SDK integration.  When I launch the scanner for the first time it works correctly. When I launch the scanner for a second time it displays the error

> SoftScan set status returned the error -43

I have checked Socket barcode scanner support but not found anything useful.

Please suggest how to handle this error.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is about but maybe you are not supposed to launch multiple instances of whatever this SDK is doing. Try reusing the same object/handle instead of creating a new one or see if theres something you should do to terminate them properly before creating another.

Comment: Thanks a lot Heavenard. This resolves my issue, now working fine.